# Optimize the queue job on sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, sidekiq, cron-task

I am using sidekiq for background job in my rails application and I have 2 workers that each worker owns 25 process. One worker is used for reading the feed-data and the other one is used to search the feed-data with specific key word provided. And there are a lot of feed url to read for search. I also use the elastic-search for searching. However within this 2 worker it consumes a lot of resource on the server. I am almost stuck to run it on the amazon small instance. So do you have any idea or better solution for this process ?

Comment: Get a bigger machine.

Comment: The reason is I cannot upgrade the instance because some limitation so is there any only solution to optimize the process?